# Proving Harnack for viscosity solutions

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde

In reference to Theorem 4.8 '[Fully Nonlinear Elliptic Equations](https://bookstore.ams.org/coll-43)' by Caffarelli and Cabre. We are asked to prove two things given $u\in \overline{S}(\lambda,\Lambda,f), u\geq 0$ in $Q_1$, and $f$ is continuous and bounded in $Q_1$.

The proof for (1) mentioned in the book proves the result for $u\in \overline{S}(\lambda,\Lambda,f)$ in $Q_{4\sqrt{n}} $

and establishes that $\|u\|_{L^{p_0}(Q_1)} \leq C(\inf_{Q_3}u+\|f\|_{L^n(Q_{4\sqrt{n}})})$

Then mentions that the desired result can be obtained with rescaling and a covering argument. 
Can anyone please help fill the details of what is left in the proof?